# Eleminate noise from a Relay in ArduinoFFT

Tags: relay

I have built a circuit with an Arduino Nano to measure frequency from my music, it's basically [this schema](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/mircemk/diy-fft-audio-spectrum-analyzer-ca2926) but I changed the code a little bit to fit my needs.

My problem is I want to add a Relay (I have an arduino single relay module) to the circuit and when I connect the signal on my 5v, it create a lot of noise in the frequency I get from ArduinoFFT.

What my code is doing is getting an average of the frequency to detect if music is currently playing. Here is a sample of data I get when there is no music playing:

```
2 2 2 4 1 0 0: 1
2 2 4 1 0 0 1: 1
4 4 1 0 0 1 0: 1
1 1 0 0 1 0 4: 1
0 0 0 1 0 4 1: 1
0 0 1 0 4 1 5: 1
1 1 0 4 1 5 3: 2
0 0 4 1 5 3 2: 2
4 4 1 5 3 2 0: 2
1 1 5 3 2 0 0: 1
```

Here, this is with music (good old rock :) ):

```
16 16 22 17 20 21 29: 20
22 22 17 20 21 29 28: 22
17 17 20 21 29 28 22: 22
20 20 21 29 28 22 25: 24
21 21 29 28 22 25 28: 25
29 29 28 22 25 28 27: 26
28 28 22 25 28 27 32: 27
22 22 25 28 27 32 27: 26
25 25 28 27 32 27 29: 28
28 28 27 32 27 29 23: 27
```

And finaly when I connect the relay (with arduino digital pin or if I jump it with the 5v, it the same result):

```
5 5 5 6 4 4 7: 5 
5 5 6 4 4 7 5: 5 
6 6 4 4 7 5 4: 5 
4 4 4 7 5 4 4: 4 
4 4 7 5 4 4 5: 4 
7 7 5 4 4 5 4: 4 
5 5 4 4 5 4 4: 4 
4 4 4 5 4 4 4: 4 
4 4 5 4 4 4 6: 4 
5 5 4 4 4 6 4: 4
```

The problem with this is that when I'm playing smooth music, the numbers are not that high, it's basically the same as when the relay is on.

Here is a schema of what I did, it's my first try, let me know if anything is not fine with it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTwvKW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: That is what my setup look like]

Comment: How are you trying to connect this relay and can you show us the noise you get?

Comment: Separate the relay power from Arduino, if that not what you want, we can only guessing because you didn't provide much info for troubleshooting.

Comment: I added more details on the data I have and a picture of my setup.

Comment: Please consider a schematic; it’s difficult to see what’s going on here.

Comment: @DaveNewton, here it is, it's my first attempt to create a schema so, I hope everything is fine with it ;)

Comment: what are you switching with the relay? If it's DC, I would use a MOSFET instead.

Comment: @dandavis, no, it's AC.